# Green clubs and blue diamonds

Tags: playing-cards

I really like the idea of making and playing cards with blue diamonds and green clubs. Each color is a separate color then.
Is there some arguments against it? Do you know some games where this would be a bad idea?

Comment: Note that your choices of colours aren't color-blind friendly

Comment: German Cards have green (leaves) istead of black spades: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_playing_cards

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Four-color-Deck/dp/B07BZW6QCY

Answer (score 3):

There are already some games that use this type of deck; such as Tichu. A Tichu deck contains 4 suits in 4 different colors (although they are not the same traditional 4 suits).

For most games out there; this idea would make the games slightly easier to play; because it would be easier to distinguish a Spade from a Club, and a Heart from a Diamond. Most traditional trick-taking or melding games would benefit from this.

However, there are a few games where not only suit, but color, also matters:

Canasta - Red 3s have separate rules from black 3s. It doesn't matter whether a 3 is a Spade or a Club, but it does matter if it's black. To play Canasta with your custom deck; you would have to remember that both a Club and a Spade have one rule, while a Heart and a Diamond have another rule.

Klondike Solitaire - Red cards can be moved onto black cards and vice-versa. So again, this would be more difficulty to play with your custom deck; as you would have to look for cards of 2 different specific suits rather than just look for cards of a specific color.

Comment: Also Euchre, where the jack of the same color as the trump suit becomes part of the trump suit